Scraping language change
I'm following a course. It's a bit outdated so some stuff changed on the website
https://www.centris.ca/
Basically it's a real estate website, you need to call 2 endpoints to get a result with properties.
Call 1: https://www.centris.ca/property/UpdateQuery
Call 2: https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions
Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how not to return the response in French. Things I tried:
headers:  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.6'
Cookies: Nothing that indicates language
Spider:
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import json


class ListingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "listings"
    allowed_domains = ["www.centris.ca"]

    position = {
        "startPosition": 0
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        query = {
            "query":{
                "UseGeographyShapes":0,
                "Filters":[
                    
                ],
                "FieldsValues":[
                    {
                        "fieldId":"Category",
                        "value":"Commercial",
                        "fieldConditionId":"",
                        "valueConditionId":""
                    },
                    {
                        "fieldId":"SellingType",
                        "value":"Rent",
                        "fieldConditionId":"",
                        "valueConditionId":""
                    },
                    {
                        "fieldId":"RentPrice",
                        "value":0,
                        "fieldConditionId":"ForRent",
                        "valueConditionId":""
                    },
                    {
                        "fieldId":"RentPrice",
                        "value":999999999999,
                        "fieldConditionId":"ForRent",
                        "valueConditionId":""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "isHomePage": True
        }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.centris.ca/property/UpdateQuery",
            method="POST",
            body=json.dumps(query),
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Language': 'en'
            },
            callback=self.update_query
        )


    def update_query(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions",
            method="POST",
            body=json.dumps(self.position),
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.6',
                'referer': 'https://www.centris.ca/en/properties~for-rent?view=Thumbnail',
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            },
            cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'},
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
       resp_dict = json.loads(response.body)
       html = resp_dict.get('d').get('Result').get('html')
       sel = Selector(text=html)
       listings = sel.xpath("//div[@class='property-thumbnail-item thumbnailItem col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3']")
       for listing in listings:
         print("not yet implemented")

Edit: I'm scraping the API, not the website itself.

Visiting the site and choosing English gets me URLs like https://www.centris.ca/en?uc=1

"I'm scraping the API, not the website itself." Then it's not really scraping, is it?

Further exploration suggests that much of the content is only available in French.

The language of the response does not appear to be based on the Accept-Language header, and I rather doubt that they are evaluating the referrer to determine this. Most likely, the chosen language will be stored in a session here, I suppose.

The selected language is stored in the session on the server, you must send the current cookie to get the data of the selected language.
You have to refactor the flow:
First of all call centris.ca/en?uc=0 to set current locale to EN then save cookie in response to local
Then send the saved cookie in the call:
https://www.centris.ca/property/UpdateQuery, https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions

Thanks, Didn't know about session storing.
